# How to split a string when elements in the string can contain the delimiter

Tags: java, json

I have a string like that:

```
String s = "{"Player":{"id":"1","name":"PM001"}},{"Player":{"id":"2","name":"PM002"}}"
```

I want to omit the "," so the result should be :

```
{"Player":{"id":"1","name":"PM001"}}

{"Player":{"id":"2","name":"PM002"}}
```

Comment: And what you have tried so far??

Comment: Where does this string come from?

Comment: It looks like a json object. Have you already tried the json-Api for Java to extract the elements?

Comment: yes i tried to use json api, i want to retreive all the id, but just i can retreive only the first id

Comment: wrap it in a pair of square brackets and parse it as json.

Comment: Looks like you need to properly parse the expression, "simple" things like straightforward string replacement or some kind of regex won't work

Comment: i did it but it got 0 and for the name null

Answer (score 3):

```
JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray(s);
newArray.get(0);
newArray.get(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for ryour reply, but an error occured "Cannot instantiate the type JSONArray"

Comment: What is the return Object of s ? String or what?

Comment: If it is not work set this String to JSONObject and call getJSONArray

Answer (score 1):

I would just split on a comma surrounded by reversed curly brackets:

```
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=}),(?=\\{)");
```

This uses look arounds to assert the presence of, but not consume, the curly brackets.